# How to create random table grid with PHP?

Tags: php, html, loops, random, html-table

I am new at PHP. I need randomized numbers from a pool to be seen in table.
I created with for loops but couldn't fill with all random numbers.
Right now unfortunately all cells show same number.

```
  <?php
    $size = 3;
    $no = array(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,2,4,6,8);
    ?>
    <table>
    <?php 
    $number[] = $no[array_rand($no)];
        for ($i=0; $i < $size; $i++){
            foreach ($number as $cell)
        { ?><tr><?php
            for ($b=0; $b < $size ;$b++){
             foreach ($number as $cell){
        echo '<td>'.$cell.'</td>';
          }
         }
         }
         ?></tr><?php
        }
        ?>
        </table>
```

Comment: Either php isn't configured correctly or you have a syntax error that is tripping up processing. We can't possibly know for sure if you don't show any code though.

Comment: you're just randomizing it once, array rand it inside when its time to print the cells. and too much `foreach` just need for loops

Comment: i dont know how to select random no from a pool without using array_rand and foreach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to just pick a random key thru `array_rand` when its time to print a single cell, so just put that in there:

```
<?php $size = 3; $no = array(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,2,4,6,8); ?>
<table border="1">
<?php for ($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++){ ?>
    <tr>
    <?php for ($b = 0; $b < $size ;$b++) { ?>
        <td><?php echo $no[array_rand($no)]; ?></td>
    <?php } ?>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
```

[Sample Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/7eQstV)

Or another way is to pick N number of keys when printing the inner loop:

```
<?php 
$size = 3; 
$no = array(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,2,4,6,8);
?>
<table>
<?php for($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++) { ?>
    <tr>
    <?php foreach(array_rand($no, $size) as $keys) { ?>
        <td><?php echo $no[$keys]; ?></td>
    <?php } ?>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
```

[Sample Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/xI0HHb)

Another weird way: (pre loaded random keys :p)

```
<?php 
$size = 3; 
$no = array(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,2,4,6,8);
$rands = array_map(function() use ($size, $no){
    return array_rand($no, $size);
}, array_fill(0, $size, array()));

?>
<table border="1">
<?php foreach($rands as $row){ ?>
    <tr><?php foreach($row as $c) { ?>
        <td><?php echo $no[$c]; ?></td>
    <?php } ?></tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
```

[Sample Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/8jHSil)

Answer (score 1):

my approach:

```
<?php
$size = 3;
$number = array(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,2,4,6,8);
shuffle($number);
$number_loop = 0;
echo '<table>';

for($i = 0; $i < $size; $i ++){
    echo '<tr>';
    for($j = 0; $j < $size; $j ++){
        echo '<td>' . $number[$number_loop] . '<td>';
        $number_loop ++;
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
?>
```

it looks like you wanted to not repeat numbers from the array, so that's what i did

demo:http://codepad.viper-7.com/65qAhA

Comment: number repeating is not a problem for this case.

Comment: in that case replace `$number[$number_loop]` with  `$number[array_rand($number)]` and remove the counter and shuffle

Answer (score -2):

```
$cells = 10;
$rows = Mathf.randomint(1,10)
cell.ctable(cells,rows,name);
$return 0
```

This should do it friend, enjoy. ;^)

Comment: is this JS ? i am trying to solve this only with html+css+php